# Cannot access account

Tags: yahoo-mail, account-recovery

I have a Yahoo email account.  I know my password.  I know all the answers to my all my secret questions.

When I try to login, Yahoo demands that I verify access through an alternate email account.  I no longer have access to that alternate email account.  I mistakenly thought simply having just a Yahoo account was a good idea and I stopped using that other account.  I was obviously wrong.

So I go to Yahoo's help system.  I click on '**Don't have access to alternate email**'.

Here are the options that Yahoo then presents:

1. What is an alternate email address?
2. Why was I notified about account access attempts?
3. Difference between alternate email address and extra email address
4. Can't edit my personal information

Those options don't have anything to do with not having access to the alternate email account.

So despite knowing my password and the answers to all my secret questions, I am locked out of my own email account.

What do I do now?  How do I get back into my account?

I never gave Yahoo a phone number, phone number approach won't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can release your account without your alternate Email account

Go to yahoo mail login page

Click the link [I can't access my account](https://edit.yahoo.com/forgotroot?done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&src=&partner=reg&intl=us&lang=en-US)

Choose the option **my account have been compromised** and proceed next

[image]

Enter you yahoo mail id

Click next to receive new password to your mobile number

Hope this helps!